# Ajax DELETE request path inconsistency

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, http-delete

I have set up an express server to handle different requests one of which is a delete request. It works some times and gives a 404 other times. I noticed that the url it is sending is different. So if I change my server code to handle one path it works until the client sends a different path. I am unable to understand why it is sending different urls and not consistent. I am very new to web programming; still a student. May be I am missing something very basic.

The request is being sent from

> http://localhost:3000/notes

page.

Yesterday the request was sent with this path:

[image]

Today the request is :

[image]

Just in case the images do not load, These are the urls:

> http://localhost:3000/api/notes/id
>
> http://localhost:3000/notes/api/notes/id

This is the client side request: (I have verified that its calling the delete with correct value)

```
    var deleteNote = function(id) {
       return $.ajax({
       url: "api/notes/" + id,
       method: "DELETE"
      });
    };
```

This is the server code:

```
    app.delete("/api/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
        let chosenNoteToDelete = req.params.id;

        fs.readFile(__dirname + "/db/db.json", (err, data) => {
         if(err){
           throw err;
         }
        let json = JSON.parse(data);

        for(let i=0; i<json.length; i++){
            if(json[i].id === chosenNoteToDelete){
               json.splice(i,1);
            }
        }

        fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/db/db.json", JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            res.send("Successfully deleted");
        })

      })

    });
```

Can someone help me understand why its inconsistent? And how do I handle it on the server?

Comment: You are using `"api/notes/" + id` but that is a relative path. Try changing it to `"/api/notes/" + id` to make it an absolute path

Comment: does using base origin help? `const base_url = window.location.origin;` and using it would be like `base_url + "api/notes/" + id `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the client code from this:

```
var deleteNote = function(id) {
   return $.ajax({
   url: "api/notes/" + id,
   method: "DELETE"
  });
};
```

to this:

```
var deleteNote = function(id) {
   return $.ajax({
   url: "/api/notes/" + id,
   method: "DELETE"
  });
};
```

Your relative path tells jQuery to combine your path with the path from the page's URL.  You don't want a relative path.  You always want it to be `/api/notes/id` so you need the leading slash.

---

Some other things to cleanup in your server code.

1. Log all possible errors with `console.log(err)` or some similar logging mechanism.
2. NEVER, EVER write `if (err) throw err` in your server inside an asynchronous callback.  That does you no good as nobody can catch that error.  Instead, you must  always log the error and then HANDLE the error by sending an error response.
3. When parsing JSON from an external source that can throw an error use `try/catch` around it.
4. When you `.splice()` an array that you are iterating, you need to either `return` after processing the `.splice()` or you need to correct the iterating index (because you just moved the array elements down that are after it so you will miss the next item in the array) or you need to iterate the array backwards so a `.splice()` operation won't affect the iteration.

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
app.delete("/api/notes/:id", (req, res) => {
    let chosenNoteToDelete = req.params.id;
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/db/db.json", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        try {
            let json = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            if (json[i].id === chosenNoteToDelete) {
                json.splice(i, 1);
                return;
            }
        }

        fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/db/db.json", JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
                return;
            }
            res.send("Successfully deleted");
        });
    });
});
```

---

And, here's a cleaner implementation using `fs.promises` and `async/await` with more centralized error handling and detection if the chosenNote is not found:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

app.delete("/api/notes/:id", async (req, res) => {
    let chosenNoteToDelete = req.params.id;
    let dataFilename = path.join(__dirname, "/db/db.json");
    try {
        let data = await fsp.readFile(dataFilename);
        let dataArray = JSON.parse(data);
        // iterate array backwards so .splice() doesn't cause us to miss elements of the array
        let found = false;
        for (let i = dataArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (dataArray[i].id === chosenNoteToDelete) {
                found = true;
                dataArray.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        if (found) {
            await fsp.writeFile(dataFilename, JSON.stringify(dataArray));
            res.send("Successfully deleted");
        } else {
            res.status(404).send(`Note id ${chosenNoteToDelete} not found.`);
        }

    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. Very helpful. Since I cannot upvote yet, I wanted to leave a comment, even though I know this section cannot be used to thank.